# mac os catalina doesn't save spotlight preferences

Tags: macos, usb, macos-catalina, spotlight

I use several external drives on my mac. Due to the fact that spotlight indexes each and every drive, and when it drive is a mechanical HDD, it slows to an halt (especially newer SMR drives). I save drive's name under "privacy" settings "Prevent Spotlight from searching these locations" on Spotlight but when I unplug drive it vanishes from the list and when I re-plug the drive, it starts indexing again.

Is there a way to make changes permanent? I really am tired of opening spotlight, adding drive and doing my work all the time I plug the same or another drive I've saved before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by putting an invisible file on the root level of each drive you don't ever want it to index - `.metadata_never_index`

This is simple enough to do from Terminal, using `touch /Volumes/NAME_OF_DRIVE/.metadata_never_index`

The same file will work for individual folders too, if you put it inside any folder you want to be ignored.